# Proving that a smooth affine variety is irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, irreducible-polynomials

I am struggling with the following problem. Given a complex polynomial $f : \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\nabla f$ doesn't vanish anywhere on the whole $\mathbb{C}^n$, $V = V(f)$ is irreducible.

I think we can solve the problem with a topological argument by saying that $f : \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a fiber bundle for the Euclidean topology and since $\mathbb{C}$ is contractible, the bundle is trivial hence $\mathbb{C}^n \cong \mathbb{C} \times F$ where $F$ is the fiber. We deduce that $F$ is connected for the Euclidean topology thus it is irreducible for the Zariski topology (because it is smooth). However, it seems to be a convoluted argument and I would like the proof to be generalisable in any algebraically closed field.

I tried by contradiction, if $V$ is reducible, then $f = gh$ for some non constant $g,h$ and $\nabla f = g\nabla h + h\nabla g \neq 0$ implies that $V(g) \cap V(h) = \emptyset$ so there exists polynomials $u,v$ such that $gu + hv = 1$. We deduce that, $fu + h^2v = h$ so, on $D(uv)$,
$$
f = -\frac{v}{u}\left(h - \frac{1}{2v}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{4uv}.
$$
In particular, $\nabla f = \frac{1}{4}\nabla\!\left(\frac{1}{uv}\right) + \mathrm{O}\!\left(h - \frac{1}{2v}\right)$. The contradiction is obvious if $uv$ is constant but not in the general case and I am stuck here. Please tell me if you have any idea (or counterexample but I doubt it exists) !

Comment: Just to understand the problem. What about $f(x,y)=(x+y)(x+y+1)$? $V(f)$ consists of 2 parallel lines, so it is reducible. But for no $(x,y)\in V(f)$ you have $\nabla f=0$, so it seems to be smooth...

Comment: I edited so it is clearer, I want $\nabla f$ to not vanish on the whole $\mathbb{C}^n$ and not only on $V(f)$. In your case, $\nabla f = (2x + 2y + 1,2x + 2y + 1)$ vanishes when $x + y = -1/2$.

Comment: I think, in order for $\nabla f$ to not vanish anywhere it would have to be constant...

Comment: No, take $f(x,y) = x^2 - y$, we have $\nabla f(x,y) = (2x,1)$ is non constant.

Comment: The usual algebraic geometry version of this statement is "A nonempty regular connected Noetherian scheme is always integral." The proof of this follows from the fact that regular local rings are always integral domains.  If there exist multiple components with nonempty intersection, the local ring at any point in that intersection would not be an integral domain, hence non-regular.

Comment: I know that if $V(g) \cap V(h)$ is non empty of codimension $\geqslant 2$, $V(g) \cup V(h)$ is singular at $V(g) \cap V(h)$. But here, a problem occurs in the case where $V(g) \cap V(h) = \emptyset$. In other words, I don't know if $V(f)$ is connected or not, it is what I want to prove.

Comment: I think the last paragraph of your question points towards a counterexample.  Consider $g=x$ and $h=xy -1$.  The gradient of $f=gh$ never vanishes, but the curve defined by $f=0$ is not irreducible.

Comment: Indeed, it works as a counterexample, thanks !